# blender lighting, image animation scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, animation, blender, scenekit

I am currently developing using `Blender` and Xcode `Scenekit`. Basically, I found that animating animations that are used to plant skeletons in images is compatible.

And if I export to `Collada` file, I can adjust basic Move, Rotation, Scale. But there was something impossible. The energy change animation of the lamp, the adjustment of the alpha value of the image is not applied to the keyframe in the timeline, the change value in `Scenekit`.

When importing a `Blender Collada` file from `Scenekit`, is it not possible to change the values of `Lamp Energy` and `Alpha` in `Blender`? If possible, please teach me how.

This is a very important issue for me. Thank you for reading the question.